# Large default width of text input prevents table to fit the smallest cell

Tags: html, css

I have a text input in a data cell, and a header cell of the same column. I expect the hierarchy of calculating width would be header >> column >> text-input, since there's no explicit width setting of text-input. But it turns out the text input has a default width which makes it wider than the header, and thus determines the width of the column.

This the link to the code

```css
.style-table {
  text-align: left;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="style-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white;">
      <th>gears</th>
      <th>rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X1</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X1-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X10</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X2-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X100</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X3-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ricecakebear/5686z44L/.

So how do I remove the default width of the text input, and let header determins the width of the column? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`input` has a browser default of `size = "20"`

1. Add `size = "1"` to the `input` to reset this.
2. In addition, include your original css (`width = 100%`). This will allow the `input` to expand to match the `th`.
3. Also include `box-sizing` property to account for `border` (or reset this instead)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/e4yaa7g3/1/)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.style-table {
  text-align: left;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="style-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white;">
      <th>gears</th>
      <th>rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X1</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X1-text" type="text" value="0" size="1" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X10</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X2-text" type="text" value="0" size="1" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X100</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X3-text" type="text" value="0" size="1" />
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="style-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white;">
      <th>gears</th>
      <th>A longer heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X1</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X1-text" type="text" value="0" size="1" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X10</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X2-text" type="text" value="0" size="1" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X100</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X3-text" type="text" value="0" size="1" />
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice explanation and solution. Actually I tried setting width of td to 1 before posting. Although it turned out to be the same result, the VS editor showed a literal 1px td which I think is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `width:100%;` for your input, you are not limiting the width of your column td.

So the input will take the default width.

```css
.style-table {
  text-align: left;
}
.style-input-td{
  width:50px;
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="style-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white;">
      <th>gears</th>
      <th>rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X1</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X1-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X10</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X2-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X100</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X3-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If there a way without explicitly setting any width and solely let the content of the header determines the width?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without defining the width of an element, setting 100% will allow it to take size as much available.

Answer (score 0):

You can add width in `th` as you want

```css
.style-table {
  text-align: left;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="style-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white;">
      <th width="60%">gears</th>
      <th width="40%">rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X1</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X1-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X10</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X2-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style-header-column">X100</td>
      <td class="style-input-td">
        <input id="X3-text" type="text" value="0" />
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If there a way without explicitly setting any width and solely let the content of the header determines the width?